# Volvo V60 T5 service schedule

Tags: volvo, service-intervals, v60

I am looking to buy a second hand Volvo V60 2021. Before I make the trip to the dealer I would like to know what is the normal service maintenance schedule for this model?
It seems it has been serviced every 18000 miles. Is that what Volvo recommends? Never owned a Volvo before, so it seems a bit too excessive for me compared to my previous cars, especially so much miles without engine oil change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Volvo maintenance schedule](https://volvornt.harte-hanks.com/manuals/2021/2021%20Models%20(non-BEV)/Volvo_Wty_Manual_2021_CC_05-29-2020.pdf) (pg 5), it states:

> The correct oil and filter interval is every 10,000 miles = 16,000 km or 12 months WHICHEVER COMES FIRST.

It looks to me like the 18k is a bit excessive as well.